# Why view added to uicollectionview cell is not appearing which is added during selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I added a view to `collectionView cell` on selection and reloaded item but the view is not visible on first selection ,its *visible only on clicking cell again*.After the first load of collectionView,on first selection of collectionView cell ,view added is being added but is not visible, the size is increased,only view is visible after second selection.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
  PastPicksGameCollectionViewCell *cell = (PastPicksGameCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,122, 150, 120)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:view]
   [pastPicksGameCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath]];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout  *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath]) {
    return CGSizeMake(320, 200);
}
return CGSizeMake(300, 120);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` is working against you: it causes the collectionView to discard the cell associated with that item (i.e. the cell you have just added the subview to) and to load from the queue a new cell (which doesn't have the subview) for that item.  The discarded cell is placed on the queue for re-use.  When you click again, the same thing happens.  But this time, the originally discarded cell (which does have the subView) is re-used, hence being displayed.

Personally, I would avoid adding subviews to cells like this - I would add a "permanent" UIView property to your custom cell class which you can then use in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.  But you must ensure in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` that you reset it (e.g. with `if (indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath) { create/show the subview } else { hide the subview/set to nil) }`.